# how to iterate through files in directory with multiple folders, operate on files, save to different set of folders

Tags: python, os.walk

I want to iterate through pdf files in all folders in a directory, operate on those files (extract text, save to .txt), then save all txt to a different set of folders with the same names but in a different directory. The function performs as intended, but not with subfolders. I understand that there is os.walk but am shaky with how to use it here. The function works if I have all the files with no subfolders; it writes to the desired directory. But I need to walk over the folders, save to those folders in the other directory.

Have found files in one directory, operated, saved to another. Trying os.walk but not successfully incorporating folder structure.

folder structure basically path/folder1...folderN

Have 30K+ files, so want to keep to folder system.

```
def convertall(pdfDir, txtDir):
    if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.walk(path) + "\\" 
    for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir):     --- tried os.walk here too; 
        fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension == "pdf":
            pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
            text = convert(pdfFilename)
            textFilename = txtDir + pdf + ".txt"
            textFile = open(textFilename, "w") 
            textFile.write(text)     

pdfDir = pdfpath
txtDir = txtpath   
convertall(pdfDir)
```

Planning to do this for various operations, so hoping to learn some general solution.

Comment: Can you show your `os.walk` attempt? If you want to recursively traverse a bunch of folders, that's definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` called with `topdown=True` returns a tuple on each iteration in the format `(this_directory_path, directories_in_this_directory, files_in_this_directory)`. The second and third elements of the tuple are lists, which means you will have to iterate through them too. So you can walk through the directory structure like this:

```
import os


def create_my_new_path(old_root)
    # This gives us everything after /home/user/PDFs, e.g. folderN
    relative_path = os.path.relpath(old_root, "/home/user/PDFs")
    # This returns "/home/user/TXTs/folderN"
    return os.path.join("/home/user/TXTs", relative_path)

for root, directories, files in os.walk("/home/user/PDFs", topdown=True):
    for pdf_filename in files:
        # Use .lower() for the comparison in case there are files that end in ".PDF"
        if pdf_filename[-4:].lower() == ".pdf":
            # the variable `root` may not contain the absolute path
            # depending on what you passed to os.walk, so you might
            # want to use os.path.abspath(root) before passing it 
            # to the path builder
            txt_save_dir = create_my_new_path(root)
            txt_filename = "".join(old_filename[:-4], ".txt")
            result = parse_PDF(os.path.join(root, filename))
            with open(os.path.join(txt_save_dir, txt_filename), "w") as f:
                f.write(result)
    for directory in directories:
        # If you wanted to do something with the subfolders too, you could do it here
        continue
```

I hope this example was easy enough to understand so you can adapt it to your needs.

Some tips:

1. It is recommended to use `os.path.join` to create file paths instead of concatenation because it will automatically add the OS's appropriate separator if it's missing. If you forget to make sure the folder and file are separated, then it will write to the wrong location.
2. `with open(path, mode) as myfile:` is a good way to open files because it will automatically close the file at the end of the `with` clause for you, even if exceptions are thrown. This is how the official python tutorial recommends you open files now. https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Here are all the `os.path` operations: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Usage for `os.walk` can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: Thanks so much; this is really helpful. And it worked perfectly well of course.